# How can I duplicate and upload an already uploaded mario maker course?

Tags: super-mario-maker-2

So I'm on Mario maker 2 3.0, and I just uploaded a short course I want to expand on, and perhaps upload the expanded version on a later date. So I selected my course, selected "save as" to duplicate it, but the new saves course says it's already uploaded so I can't upload it. How can I modify and upload the course without removing it from course world or starting from scratch?

Answer (score 1):

Once you upload a level, it gets marked as uploaded (with a small up arrow icon in the level selection menu), and cannot be reuploaded unless you delete the uploaded level from course world.

Even if you save a copy of the level in a new slot after uploading it, the marker will stay and the copy also cannot be uploaded unless the original level is first deleted from course world.

However, if you make a copy of your level *before* uploading it, the copy will *not* be marked as uploaded.  So you can in fact upload as many different versions of your level as you like, as long as you remember to **always save a backup copy before you upload the level.**

Alas, if you already uploaded your level and forgot to make a backup copy, there's nothing (AFAIK) you can do except delete the level from course world.  At least, when you do that, *all* copies of the level that you've saved after uploading it will have the upload marker removed from them, so you can then reupload each of them as separate levels.

<sup>(This answer is based on testing I just did in MM2.  My apologies to everyone who ended up playing my awful test levels.)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

In short, you can't .

All you can do is try to delete the previous upload course......